# What's the fastest way to convert List<string> to List<int> in C# assuming int.Parse will work for every item?

Tags: c#, performance, list, generics

By fastest I mean what is the most *performant* means of converting each item in List to type int using C# assuming int.Parse will work for every item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is likely to be very little difference between any of the obvious ways to do this: therefore go for readability (one of the LINQ-style methods posted in other answers).

You may gain some performance for very large lists by initializing the output list to its required capacity, but it's unlikely you'd notice the difference, and readability will suffer:

```
List<string> input = ..
List<int> output = new List<int>(input.Count);
... Parse in a loop ...
```

The slight performance gain will come from the fact that the output list won't need to be repeatedly reallocated as it grows.

Comment: I suspect that this is done automatically by BCL when you invoke ToList() on an List<T>. If this is true you gain nothing and you made your code less readable. For example: myListOfStrings.Count() doesn't iterate to get the count but it uses myListOfStrings.Count property.

Comment: @Petar, yes this micro-optimization is done when you invoke ToList() on a List<T> (in fact on any ICollection<T>).  But the Linq methods in other answers return an IEnumerable<T>, in which case it won't be done.  Nevertheless I agree with your remark about readability, which I hope is obvious from the answer.

Comment: Added explanation in my answer. Regards.

Answer (score 6):

You won't get around iterating over all elements. Using LINQ:

```
var ints = strings.Select(s => int.Parse(s));
```

This has the added bonus it will only convert at the time you iterate over it, and only as  much elements as you request.

If you really need a list, use the `ToList` method. However, you have to be aware that the performance bonus mentioned above won't be available then.

Comment: This will return an IEnumerable<int>, not List<int>.

Answer (score 5):

If you're really trying to eeke out the last bit of performance you could try doing someting with pointers like [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/unsafe-parse), but personally I'd go with the simple linq implementation that others have mentioned.

```
unsafe static int ParseUnsafe(string value)
{
int result = 0;
fixed (char* v = value)
{
    char* str = v;
    while (*str != '\0')
    {
    result = 10 * result + (*str - 48);
    str++;
    }
}
return result;
}

var parsed = input.Select(i=>ParseUnsafe(i));//optionally .ToList() if you really need list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var myListOfInts = myListString.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList()
```

Side note: If you call ToList() on ICollection .NET framework automatically preallocates an
List of needed size, so it doesn't have to allocate new space for each new item added to the list.

Unfortunately LINQ Select doesn't return an ICollection (as Joe pointed out in comments).

From ILSpy:

```
// System.Linq.Enumerable
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
if (source == null)
{
    throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
}
return new List<TSource>(source);
}

// System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
if (collection == null)
{
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);
}
ICollection<T> collection2 = collection as ICollection<T>;
if (collection2 != null)
{
    int count = collection2.Count;
    this._items = new T[count];
    collection2.CopyTo(this._items, 0);
    this._size = count;
    return;
}
this._size = 0;
this._items = new T[4];
using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        this.Add(enumerator.Current);
    }
}
}
```

So, ToList() just calls List constructor and passes in an IEnumerable.
The List constructor is smart enough that if it is an ICollection it uses most efficient way of filling a new instance of List

Comment: I don't see how this can be made more faster with retaining requested functionality and without seriously sacrifice readability.

Comment: @Peter " if it is an ICollection ..." - true, but irrelevant in this specific case because the output of Select isn't an ICollection<T>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the performance implications are, but there is a `List<T>.ConvertAll<TOutput>` method for converting the elements in the current List to another type, returning a list containing the converted elements.

[List.ConvertAll Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx#Y700)